# VPN only for some applications on the iPad

Tags: ipad, connection, vpn

We are creating an application for the iPad. Because of sensitivity of the data in the application, the data transfer should be over VPN. Before launching the application the user has to establish a VPN connection.

How do we make sure at the same time that other applications like YouTube don't use the VPN and only the application which we created for the iPad uses VPN?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a VPN you do not have to "tunnel the whole network" (in fact it´s not nice to do so as local servers will become unreachable), you can decide on which ports, services, IPs to tunnel; so if you try to  reach secretserver.example.com you do use the secure connection and if you try to reach google.com you don´t use it.

You could even think of using VPN on Demand (for more info I´d suggest having a closer look at [Apple´s iOS Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://images.apple.com/ie/iphone/business/docs/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf))

> VPN On Demand:
>   For certificate-based IPSec configurations, you can turn on VPN On Demand so that a VPN connection is automatically established when accessing certain domains.

Comment: VPN On Demand works only for certificate-based authentication. But, we would like to use RSA SecurID based authentication. Is there a way for some traffic to go through the VPN tunnel and the rest not through the VPN tunnel when using RSA SecurID?

Comment: As I said, you can (and should) configure your VPN setup to only tunnel connection requests made to a predefined range of IPs (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling). This has nothing to do with iOS, you will have to have a closer look at your current VPN setup and see how that works right now (and whether you need to reconfigure it).

Comment: Does OpenVPN count as "certificate based" VPNs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. As a rule of thumb, no 3rd party app (like yours would be) can prevent, alter, influence or (in many cases) tell what the iOS apps (such as mail or youtube) or iOS itself are doing.

The only way for an app to interact with it's environment are things like local notifications, adding calendar entries and the like.

In your case, you'd propably need to establish some sort of secure connection within the system provided communication channels to make sure no other app will be able to talk on the same layer as your app does.